# confusionMatrix in R

Tags: r, pattern-recognition

I'm studying pattern recognition, so I make 2 classes of data and separated it using my model.
My data only can assume two values, true and false.

for plot my results I used confusionMatrix, and when I was interpreting the result a doubt happens.

Can confusionMatrix give me a false accuracy ? For example:

I have 10 itens, 5 true and 5 false, my classifier predict 8 correct and 2 wrongs,so 1 of wrong should be true and was classified was false and other item should be false and was true. 
In this case the result are 5 true and 5 false.
in "Help" of R Studio I cannot see if confusionMatrix compare item by item or only sum of possibles results.

Comment: Which package are you using?? I assume `caret` however there are others with `confusionMatrix` as a function.  Also, could you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please save the RStudio tag for questions about the code editor RStudio (for example, if your code worked on the command line and the RGui, but didn't work in RStudio).

Answer (score 2):

I´m using confusionMatrix from library "RSNNS".

I make a simple example to test and understand better how confucionMatrix from RSNNS works.

```
rm(list = ls())
library("RSNNS")


targetsDados <- 1*c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
targetsPredictions <- 1*c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)


confusionMatrix(targetsDados,targetsPredictions)
```

targetsPredictions have 2 differents values, but same number of '0' and '1' than targetsDados.

The result of this script is:

```
       predictions
targets 0 1
      0 4 1
      1 1 4
```

So confusionMatrix give to me how many predictions are wrong, comparing item by item.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by false accuracy ? Do you imply 'False Positive' ? Given your case the confusion matrix Looks something like( A represents Actual , P represents model predicts ) :

```
     A.T  A.F
P.T  4    1 
P.F  1    4
```

Now there are multiple things you can calculate here :

True positive Rate ( Precision ) = 4/5

True negative Rate ( i think this is what you are looking for ) = 4/5

```
# where model got wrong
```

False Positive Rate = 1/5

False Negative Rate = 1/5

Accuracy ( overall what it got right ) = 8/10

```
#to get the above ( not using confusion matrix from `caret` )

a=4 # correct positives
b=1 # incorrect positive
c=4 # correct negative 
d=1 # incorrect negative 

TPR = a/(a+b)
TNR = d/(c+d)
FPR = b/(b+d)
FNR = c/(a+c)
Accuracy = (a+d)/(a+b+c+d)
```